# NSDateFormatterLongStyle string to NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I have a UIDataPicker in my viewController with default location, when my user finishes selecting the date I run this code:

```
NSString *dateString = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:[self.dataPicker date]
                                                          dateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle
                                                  timeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
```

With that code I can storage the date in the following format:

> May 31, 2016

Later in my code I need to convert this string into a real date format, for this I use the code below:

```
-(NSDate*)convertStringToDate:(NSString*)date{
    NSString *dateString = date;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];

    return [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
}
```

But this code return a null value. As the datepicker is set by default, my system can receive any date format, but in the end I want it to be converted to the format en_us.

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: `May 31, 2016` vs `MM/dd/yyyy` Do you see the same format there? The format `MM/dd/yyyy` does not match the format of the string (`May 31, 2016`).

Comment: @Larme, I see... now let's change the language the device to french, the format will be different than May 31, 2016, I think I need to convert the date to locale...

Comment: Don't store the date as string. Keep it of type date and format it only when you need to show it to the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't store the date as a string; store it as an offset, in seconds, from some reference date.

i.e:

```
uint64_t offset = (uint64_t)[[self.dataPicker date] timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
// store this 64-bit unsigned integer.
```

This takes less space and is quicker to convert to/from an `NSDate` object.

You can leave the offset as an `NSTimeInterval` (64-bit floating point `double`) if you prefer, but as you aren't storing date & time, `uint64_t` should do...

Answer (score 1):

The formatting string depends on the locale you are using. From the `localizedStringFromDate` documentation:

> Returns string representation of a given date formatted for the
>   current locale using the specified date and time styles.
>
> This method uses a date formatter configured with the current default
>   settings. The returned string is the same as if you configured and
>   used a date formatter as shown in the following example:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.formatterBehavior = NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4;
formatter.dateStyle = dateStyle; formatter.timeStyle = timeStyle;
NSString *result = [formatter stringForObjectValue:date];
```

Means, you should do the next:

```
-(NSDate*)convertStringToDate:(NSString*)dateString {
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.formatterBehavior = NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4;
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterLongStyle;
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterNoStyle;
    return [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
}
```

Comment: `MM` should correspond for `05`, not `May`, no?

Comment: Right, Now if my user is using my app with different locate? Like french, japan, portuguese... this code can handle? (once my picker is set to default)

Comment: Yeah, the formatting string should depend the locale you were using to create the date. Updated the solution accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code,

```
-(NSDate*)convertStringToDate:(NSString*)date{
    NSString *dateString = date;
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM d, yyyy"];

    return [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
}
```

hope its helpful